# Async is becoming a pain in the behind because I'm trying to make a re-usable library that doesn't suck

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

Because Post requests to APIs need to run asynchronously on windows phone, I am struggling to create a lean easy to use library to interact with an API.

The issue is that people using the library will always need to supply a callback function.

Let's take a look at some pseudo code:

**PostRequest Class to help me with POST requests:**

```
class PostRequest
{
    private Action<MemoryStream> Callback;

    public PostRequest(string urlPath, string data, Action<MemoryStream> callback)
    {
        Callback = callback;

        // Form the URI
        UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(urlPath);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            fullUri.Query = data;

        // Initialize a new WebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri.Uri);
        request.Method = "POST";

        // Set up the state object for the async request
        DataUpdateState dataState = new DataUpdateState();
        dataState.AsyncRequest = request;

        // Start the asynchronous request
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleResponse),
            dataState);
    }

    private void HandleResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Get the state information
        DataUpdateState dataState = (DataUpdateState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebRequest dataRequest = (HttpWebRequest)dataState.AsyncRequest;

        // End the async request
        dataState.AsyncResponse = (HttpWebResponse)dataRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        if (dataState.AsyncResponse.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            // Create a stream from the response
            Stream response = dataState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(response, true);
            string jsonString = textReader.ReadToEnd();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));

            // Send the stream through to the callback function
            Callback(stream);
        }
    }
}

public class DataUpdateState
{
    public HttpWebRequest AsyncRequest { get; set; }
    public HttpWebResponse AsyncResponse { get; set; }
}
```

**The API Access Object classes:**

```
class APIAuthenticationCredentials
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}

class APIAO
{
    private String AuthUrl = "http://api.example.com/";
    public static Auth Auth = new Auth();

    //... 
    public static void Authenticate( String data, APIAuthenticationCredentials credentials, Action<MemoryStream> callback )
    {
        PostRequest request = new PostRequest(AuthURL, data, callback);   
    }
    //... 
}
```

You will notice I have to pass a callback function all the way through this so that once the data is returned by the **HandleResponse** method in my **PostRequest** class, the data is forwarded onto some controller that makes the screen do something with the data. At the moment, it's not ultra horrid to use:

```
private void DisplayData(MemoryStream stream)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Auth));
    APIAO.Auth = (Auth)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}

//...    
    APIAuthenticationCredentials credentials = new APIAuthenticationCredentials {
        Username = "whatever",
        Password = "whatever"
    }    
    APIAO.Authenticate( credentials, DisplayData );
//...
```

The problem is I want to create some kind of repository style pattern... Let's say the API returned different json models, one call returned an array of products... the problem is that I want to create one lovely repository call eg:

```
IProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository();
productRepository.GetAll();
```

But I've gotta put some GOSH DARN callback function in it too and that means every repository method of any object type returned by the API is going to have this MemoryStream callback... and if I ever want to change that functionality, I've gotta update that stuff everywhere yo. :(
Has anyone seen a better way of doing this crap.

This is starting to become far too complex

--crying

Comment: Hashtags don't work on their own line. #sorry

Comment: I don't see `async / await` anywhere in your code. - `C#` will surely suck for you if you use it like java.

Comment: ah man, I am so uber new to C# and especially windows phone, please, if you see anything that makes you laugh, post it as an answer.. Anything you see there that looks dumb and can be corrected, i'm going to be hugging you for. What does your comment suggest? alas, please see the postrequest class that contains dataState.AsyncResponse calls

Comment: @HighCore Or if you use it like C# 2.0, as the case is here.

Comment: Use it like java? What's java, never heard of it... :) I am coming from C#.NET MVC 4.0 framework.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. Are you opposed to just wrapping your calls to utilize the the async/await pattern?

Comment: No, I do not know any better! Please post an answer if i'm being a dummy! I have built this all from 'Bing'ing (that'll never catch on). I'm now reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: `What's java` - nothing important. it's just a crappy dinosaur language that had a niche before C# became the king of all programming languages.

Comment: Hangon, I'm trying to install the Http Client and it doesn't have an assembly for windows phone. ffs, I've had this issue before guys!!! This is all good until you try use it on windows phone 8 (VS 2012)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simpler answer using newer language constructs would be:

```
public static Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
{
    UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(url);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        fullUri.Query = data;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;//TODO update as needed
    return client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(fullUri.Uri);
}
```

In a 4.0 project you can use a `TaskCompletionSource` to translate a non-Task asynchronous model into a `Task`:

```
public static Task<string> GetData2(string url, string data)
{
    UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(url);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        fullUri.Query = data;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;//TODO update as needed

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Error != null)
            tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
        else if (args.Cancelled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(fullUri.Uri);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The caller now has a `Task<string>` that represents the results of this asynchronous operation.  They can wait on it synchronously and get the result using the `Result` property, they can add a callback that will execute when the operation finishes using `ContinueWith`, or they can `await` the task in an `async` method which, under the hood, will wire up the remainder of that method as a continuation of that task, but without creating a new method or even a new scope, i.e.

```
public static async Task Foo()
{
    string result = await GetData("http://google.com", "");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This will start the asynchronous task, add a callback (or continuation) to that task so that when it runs it will continue executing code where it left off, at which point it will then write the results to the console and mark the `Task` that *this* method returns as completed, so that any continuations to *this* method will then execute (allowing for composition of `async` methods).

Comment: Ohhhh mama, let me try and implement this shizzle

Comment: DownloadStringTaskAsync is not being found as a method of client. Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesT You're apparently not using .NET 4.5.  Are you in a position to be able to upgrade?

Comment: Ofcourse! Is that defined in the project properties assembly versioning?

Comment: @JamesT It's in the project properties, yes.  The framework version is a build setting.

Comment: Just to clarify *why* this is better than callbacks: the `Task` logically packages up the work that is being done and allows `await` to register a callback automatically. The callbacks are still there, but hidden.

Comment: Yea... and also it's like 10 lines vs a trillion. What a waste of my time ay... hm, framework version is a build setting, but not a simple dropdown I suppose :( I'll bing it, bear with and thanks for all your help!

Comment: @usr To further clarify, it inverts how the callbacks are applies to the asynchronous operations.  Rather than every single asynchronous operation needing to know about all of it's callbacks in advance, the asynchronous object just defines it's own asynchrony and then can be passed around willy nilly, having callbacks (continuations) added by the callers.  That, and it greatly improve support for exceptions, cancellation, etc.

Comment: `TaskFactory.FromAsync` is another thing to look at if you are stuck with .net4

Comment: Argh, how do I define my windows phone app as .NET 4.5!!! The project properties shows nothing and the solution properties has the platform blanked out as an aoption

Comment: @JamesT Not really sure, as I'm not a winphone developer, but I would imagine it should be possible.  If memory serves it was one of the bigger reasons to add `async` support in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you can change the platform in VS2012 express?

Comment: I can't use this solution because I simply cannot change the .net 4.5 framework!

Comment: @JamesT You can use .NET 4.5 in VS2012 express, I know that.  As I've said, not sure what it takes to get it working for a winphone project.

Comment: You can install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` into a WinPhone project and get extension methods for `WebClient`. An alternative is to install `Microsoft.Net.Http` and use `HttpClient` instead (I recommend newer development be done with `HttpClient`).

Comment: There is no .NET Framework targeting for Windows Phone projects. They use a pared down distribution of Silverlight, so the above Bcl NuGet package is the best choice for async web request processing in WP. You will need to choose **Include Prerelease** from the search dropdown in NuGet when locating the package online.